# How do I graph $r = 3 - 3\sin \theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

How can I draw the graph of
$$r = 3 - 3\sin \theta$$
in polar coordinates?
I know it's a Cardioid, but I'm not sure how to get the graph step by step.

Comment: Start with the Cartesian graph first.

Comment: @Nameless How do I convert this specific graph into a Cartesian graph? I tried multiplying both sides by r and substituting *x^2 +y^2 = r^2*. Then completing the square  which gives no Cartesian graph because the right side has an r term I can't cancel. I

Comment: Consider $\theta$ to be the angle made by the line joining the point you want to plot and the origin, with the positive direction of the x - axis. Take the origin as one end - point of a line segment along this line and take the length of this line segment to be $3 -  3sin\theta$, the other end point of this line segment is the required point. Do this for different values of $\theta$

Comment: This cannot be represented as an explicit function by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The cardioid cannot be represented as graph of an implicit function. However if we consider only the region in the first quadrant, we can represent the graph as the graph of an imlplicit function

we will have $sin\theta = {y\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and so you'll get
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 3 - 3{y\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ i.e. $${x^2 + y^2\over 3} + y = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$$ squaring you' ll get $${{(x^2+y^2)}^2\over 9} + {2y(x^2+y^2)\over 3} = x^2$$ which you can plot using some graph plotter

Answer (score 1):

**The engineer's approach**

The simplest approach (for graphing) is the following

$$x(\theta)=r(\theta)\cos(\theta)=3(1-\sin(\theta))\cos(\theta)$$
and
$$y(\theta)=r(\theta)\sin(\theta)=3(1-\sin(\theta))\sin(\theta).$$
Now, list the values of $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, say, in steps of $0.05$ and put marks at the points determined by $(x(\theta),y(\theta)).$

With an Excel you can do the graph in a second:

[image]

Of course, I appreciate the other answer showing that our curve not only looks like a cardioid but it actually is a cardioid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at $r=1-\sin\theta$ the curve we're looking for is obtained by a dilation of a factor $3$.

We first notice that $r(\pi-\theta)=r(\theta)$ and therefore the curve is invariant by a y-axis reflection. We can limit our study to the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Next we note that $r(-\pi/2)=2$, $r(0)=1$ and $r(\pi/2)=0$ and therefore the curve passes through $(-2,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ and at the origin the tangent is the vertical positive semi axis.

At any point of the curve a tangent vector is $(dr/d\theta,r)$ in the local reference frame and $dr/d\theta=-\cos\theta$. This has the following consequences.

It confirms that for $\theta=\pi/2$ we have a singularity and we have a cusp point.

For $\theta=-\pi/2$ the tangent vector in the local frame is $(0,2)$ so the tangent is horizontal in the $x,y$ frame and points to the $x\geq 0$

For $\theta=0$ the tangent vector in the local frame is $(-1,1)$ and the tangent is parallel to the second diagonal $y=-x$.

Let's look for other points where the tangent is horizontal. In the local frame a tangent vector is $(-\cos\theta,1-\sin\theta)$, and it transforms into $(-\cos{2\theta}-\sin\theta,-\sin{2\theta}+\cos\theta)$. The tangent is horizontal when

$$\sin{2\theta}=\cos{\theta}=\sin{{\pi\over 2}-\theta}$$

And this is solved with $2\theta=\pi/2-\theta$ i.e. $\theta =\pi/6$ or $2\theta=-\pi/2+\theta$ i.e. $\theta=-\pi/2$ consistent with what we have already.

The tangent is vertical when

$$\cos{2\theta}=-\sin{\theta}=\cos{{\pi\over 2}+\theta}$$

And this is solved for $2\theta=\pi/2+\theta$ i.e $\theta=\pi/2$ consistent with what we had before or $2\theta=-\pi/2-\theta$ i.e $\theta=-\pi/6$.

And this is enough to draw a cardioid with the y- axis as a symmetry axis